# how to implement a specific GATT profile to a bluetooth BLE module

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am having a small query regarding the GATT profile implementation.

That is … how can i implement a particular GATT profile on bluetooth 4.0 module..? Specifically bought a CC2541 BLE module and how can i implement a GATT profile in it,specifically a heart rate monitor profile.

Comment: What is your GATT client ?. A Smartphone or ?.

Comment: GATT client is a Android smart phone and peripheral will be the BLE module which advertise  the data..and i want to know how to implement a particular GATT profile on a BLE module.

Comment: You have to access the specific given UUIDs with your Smartphone (GATT Client). The CC2541 development kit has a given UUID for every functionality it includes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SDK they provide to program the chip.

In order to implement a GATT profile, you need to create the GATT database, containing services and characteristics.

Have a look at this:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru301a/swru301a.pdf

And the **SDK** here:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru271f/swru271f.pdf, look at page 35, you'll find the section "Complete Attribute Table" which makes it very easy to create the database.